# CORS in .NET Core 2.0 "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cors

I have created a web api using Core 2.0 and when doing cross domain calls w/ cors enabled, receive the following error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Below is my config in startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
        });

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll"));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");    
    }
```

According to every post/tutorial I see on stackoverflow or else where, this is the correct way to do it to allow all origins. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try calling: `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` **before** `app.UseMvc();`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#enabling-cors-with-middleware) states the following:

> To enable CORS for your entire application add the CORS middleware to your request pipeline using the UseCors extension method. Note that the CORS middleware must **precede** any defined endpoints in your app that you want to support cross-origin requests (ex. **before any call to UseMvc**).

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, but this tutorial should help you out.

https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/113/aspnet-core-20-angular-24-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

Below is the config in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAutoMapper();

        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```